# JButton shows different behavior with Simulated MousePress (Robot)

Tags: jbutton, awtrobot, mousepress

I wondering a bit why JButton does not shows "pressed" state after mouse press if I simulate it with Robot. The MouseEvents JButton receiving are exactly same, but outcome is different. Does Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was (as usual) that I used EDT. Just put it in another thread and it worked.